# I am trying to list all cluster in aws ECS cluster using python boto3, it can only list 100 cluster maximum and i want 300 cluster

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

```
session = boto3.Session()

client = session.client('ecs')

cluster = client.list_clusters()

clusterArns = cluster["clusterArns"]
print(clusterArns)
for i in clusterArns:
    print(i.split('/')[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

The response will contain a `nextToken` if there are any additional pages of results.

If this is returned in a response you will need to run the `client.list_clusters()` passing in this parameter again to get the next page.

The `MaxResults` of a single page can only be between 1 and 100 so there is no way to increase the maximum items returned.

You can find out more about the [list_clusters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.list_clusters) function from the documentation.

Comment: import boto3 
from pprint import pprint
client = boto3.client('ecs')
response = client.list_clusters(maxResults=100)
pprint (response['clusterArns'])
next_token = response['nextToken']
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_clusters')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
  cluster="testlist",
  PaginationConfig={
        'MaxItems': 100,
        'PageSize': 100,
        'StartingToken': next_token
    })
for i in response_iterator:
  pprint (i['serviceArns'])

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_6.py", line 7, in <module>
    next_token = response['nextToken']
KeyError: 'nextToken'

Comment: That means that `nextToken` does not exist in that response. Try `if "nextToken" in response:` to validate it first.

Comment: but in the boto3 document, they said in return response give nextToken value. But when I get a response there is not present nextToken value. WHY?                                         Returns
Response Syntax

{
    'clusterArns': [
        'string',
    ],
    'nextToken': 'string'
}

Comment: {'clusterArns': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '1979ebfb-69aa-4213-abf5-75b345a41f08', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '1979ebfb-69aa-4213-abf5-75b345a41f08', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '18', 'date': 'Wed, 24 Jun 2020 12:57:34 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}         i get only this.